# synchronize stm32 timers in encoder mode

Tags: timer, stm32

I need to use 8 Timers of 2 `Stm32f7 Nucleo` board in encoder mode to save encoder data. But I need to synchronize the timers. There are two methods to do that.

1. External clock
2. Master mode.

But in these 2 modes, you can not use timers in encoder mode.
Can anybody please help me? How can I synchronize timer in encoder mode?

Comment: Why do you need to sync them? Encoder is by definition not in sync with anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.